# Cannot run qmake in Mac Terminal

Tags: c++, macos, qt, qmake

I'm learning Qt for my C++ course at college. I am trying to set up the environment for my first assignment but I can't seem to get it right. I swear I have run qmake in the  terminal before, but now since I installed Qt 5.2 with Qt Creator I can't create the projects in the terminal.

None of the commands are recognised and on top of that if I try to compile a standard C++ file with

```
#include <QtGui>
```

the compiler won't find it. The g++ compiler that I'm using will not find any of the Qt Libraries that I try to import. I looked online and the solution I found was just to run

```
brew install qt
```

in Terminal and hope that it sorts itself out, although the terminal throws an error and won't install it once it's downloaded. I really need to get this working for my assignment.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

*** EDIT ***

Okay so I added the qmake bin into my PATH variable. This was the path:

```
/Users/#####/Qt5.2.1/5.2.1/clang_64/bin
```

The problem is that now nothing in my C++ source files are being recognized. None of the imports like QString or QTextStream or QtGui, etc. What can cause this?

Comment: can you please provide the error `qmake`(or whatever error) gave you?!

Comment: ######:~ ######$ qmake
-bash: qmake: command not found

Comment: Relevant if you are interested in Qt via MacPorts: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31318672/1959808

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Did you set the environment variable `PATH` with the path to Qt?

in Terminal do: `echo $PATH` and look for something like `/usr/local/Qt-5.x.x/bin:PATH`

If there is not any path to your installed qt, set it like this:

In .profile (if your shell is bash), add the following lines:

```
PATH=/usr/local/Qt-5.0.2/bin:$PATH
export PATH
```

To help you in the process you probably would like to read here: [QT mac install](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/install-mac.html)

**ANSWER TO NEW QUESTION**

If writing code nothing seems to be recognized you should add the link to your `include` directory. The `include` directory is where there are all the header file, so your IDE can give you suggestion about class method etc...

Comment: I haven't done this yet no, and it doesn't seem to be working. The Qt isn't installed in that path. Somehow it has made its way into just my User library installed in Qt5.2.1 and the bin folder is Qt5.2.1/5.2.1/clang64/bin. I really feel like I've done something wrong with the install. When I try install using brew it tells me that qt version 4.8.5 is installed but not linked.

Comment: of course you should put your personal path. try to locate where is exactly installed (with 'locate' from terminal) and edit the `PATH`. Otherwise if you think you have done something really wrong I suggest to uninstall and reinstall with the tutorial I provided.

Comment: I used `PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/qt5/5.7.0/bin:$PATH`. Replace `5.7.0` with whatever your version is in Homebrew

Comment: On my mac path was like this, I installed via unified dmg installer. `/Users/ishandutta2007/Qt/5.11.2/clang_64/lib`

Answer (score 4):

It is generally not needed *at all* to touch the PATH on any system (Mac, Unix, Windows) merely to use Qt. You may have multiple Qt versions installed in parallel (say 4.8 from macports, 5.2, git stable, etc.).

A way of building a Qt project on Unix is (substitute relevant paths for your setup):

```
mkdir ~/build-dir
cd ~/build-dir
~/Qt5.2.1/5.2.1/clang_64/bin/qmake ~/src/myproject/myproject.pro
make -j2
# were N in -jN is the number of CPU cores on your system
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you cannot execute the program is because it's not in the `$PATH` of the shell you are using. First find where it is located and then add the directory to that binary directory to your `$PATH` environment variable. Then you'll be able to execute it in your terminal.

For instance, if you are using ZSH and your program resides in "/opt/local/bin" then execute the following to make it available through `$PATH`:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/local/bin
```

After this point you would be able to run the program. And you should add this to your shell RC file.

Answer (score 0):

If you've installed the Qt SDK then the path of qmake is not automatically included as an environment variable, so you have to do it manually. This is also true in windows. I found this weird. It should be included automatically unless there is a sensible reason behind it.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I realised that the `.bashrc` file was not getting autoloaded on a new terminal session after adding the qmake PATH to the file (using `echo 'export PATH="$(brew --prefix qt@5.5)/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc`).

So I simply run `source ~/.bashrc` and bam! It worked!

Answer (score -1):

Working on 9 APR 2020
set Path
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/qt/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile