# When trying to build a project in Qt Creator, I get the error:'ui_texo.h' file not found #include "ui_texo.h"

Tags: c++, macos, qt

My project file qt.pro is located in the same folder as a .ui file called texo.ui. From what I have read, it seems like a file ui_texo.h should be automatically generated when I try to build the project but I'm not positive. I am a Qt beginner and am quite lost. I had a similar problem initially with a file qgraphicsview.h, which I fixed by using finder to locate the file and then pasting it into the same file that qt.pro is in. Unfortunately, I can't locate a ui_texo.h file anywhere on my computer. Thanks in advance for any help, and let me know if you have any questions or if I haven't been clear!

The contents of qt.pro are:

```
QT += core gui
TARGET = qt
TEMPLATE = app

HEADERS += \
    TexoView.h \
    TexoDemo.h \
    stdafx.h \
    TexoViewImg.h \

SOURCES += \
    TexoView.cpp \
    TexoDemo.cpp \
    StdAfx.cpp \
    main.cpp \
    TexoViewImg.cpp

FORMS += \
    texo.ui

RESOURCES += \
    texo.qrc \
    texo.qrc

OTHER_FILES += \
    res/u.ico \
    res/stop.png \
    res/run.png \
    res/init.png



INCLUDEPATH += ../../inc/

LIBS += -L"../../lib/" -ltexo
LIBS += -L"../../../bin/" -ltexo
```

`
and the contents of makefile are:

```
Makefile: qt.pro ../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/macx-clang/qmake.conf ../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/features/spec_pre.prf \
        ../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/qdevice.pri \
        ../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/features/device_config.prf \
        ../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/common/shell-unix.conf \
        ../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/common/unix.conf \
        ../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/common/mac.conf \
        ../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/common/macx.conf \
        ../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/common/gcc-base.conf \
        ../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/common/gcc-base-mac.conf \
        ../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/common/clang.conf \
        ../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/common/clang-mac.conf \
        ../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/qconfig.pri \
        ../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_bluetooth.pri \
        ../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_bluetooth_private.pri \
        ../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_bootstrap_private.pri \
        ../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_clucene_private.pri \
        ../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_concurrent.pri \
        ../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_concurrent_private.pri \
        ../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_core.pri \
        ../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_core_private.pri \
        ../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_dbus.pri \
        ../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_dbus_private.pri \
        ../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_declarative.pri \
        ../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_declarative_private.pri \
        ../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_designer.pri \
        ../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_designer_private.pri \
        ../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_designercomponents_private.pri \
        ../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_enginio.pri \
        ../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_enginio_private.pri \
        ../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_gui.pri \
        ../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_gui_private.pri \
        ../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_help.pri \
        ../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_help_private.pri \
        ../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_macextras.pri \
        ../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_macextras_private.pri \
        ../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_multimedia.pri \
        ../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_multimedia_private.pri \
        ../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_multimediawidgets.pri \
        ../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_multimediawidgets_private.pri \
        ../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_network.pri \
        ../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_network_private.pri \
        ../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_nfc.pri \
        ../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_nfc_private.pri \
        ../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_opengl.pri \
        ../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_opengl_private.pri \
        ../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_openglextensions.pri \
        ../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_openglextensions_private.pri \
        ../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_platformsupport_private.pri \
        ../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_positioning.pri \
        ../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_positioning_private.pri \
        ../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_printsupport.pri \
        ../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_printsupport_private.pri \
        ../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_qml.pri \
        ../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_qml_private.pri \
        ../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_qmldevtools_private.pri \
        ../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_qmltest.pri \
        ../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_qmltest_private.pri \
        ../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_qtmultimediaquicktools_private.pri \
        ../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_quick.pri \
        ../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_quick_private.pri \
        ../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_quickparticles_private.pri \
        ../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_quickwidgets.pri \
        ../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_quickwidgets_private.pri \
        ../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_script.pri \
        ../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_script_private.pri \
        ../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_scripttools.pri \
        ../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_scripttools_private.pri \
        ../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_sensors.pri \
        ../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_sensors_private.pri \
        ../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_serialport.pri \
        ../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_serialport_private.pri \
        ../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_sql.pri \
        ../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_sql_private.pri \
        ../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_svg.pri \
        ../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_svg_private.pri \
        ../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_testlib.pri \
        ../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_testlib_private.pri \
        ../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_uitools.pri \
        ../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_uitools_private.pri \
        ../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_webkit.pri \
        ../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_webkit_private.pri \
        ../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_webkitwidgets.pri \
        ../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_webkitwidgets_private.pri \
        ../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_websockets.pri \
        ../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_websockets_private.pri \
        ../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_widgets.pri \
        ../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_widgets_private.pri \
        ../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_xml.pri \
        ../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_xml_private.pri \
        ../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_xmlpatterns.pri \
        ../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_xmlpatterns_private.pri \
        ../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/features/qt_functions.prf \
        ../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/features/qt_config.prf \
        ../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/macx-clang/qmake.conf \
        ../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/features/spec_post.prf \
        ../../../../.qmake.stash \
        ../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/features/exclusive_builds.prf \
        ../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/features/default_pre.prf \
        ../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/features/mac/default_pre.prf \
        ../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/features/resolve_config.prf \
        ../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/features/default_post.prf \
        ../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/features/mac/sdk.prf \
        ../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/features/mac/default_post.prf \
        ../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/features/mac/objective_c.prf \
        ../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/features/warn_on.prf \
        ../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/features/qt.prf \
        ../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/features/resources.prf \
        ../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/features/moc.prf \
        ../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/features/unix/opengl.prf \
        ../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/features/unix/thread.prf \
        ../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/features/mac/rez.prf \
        ../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/features/testcase_targets.prf \
        ../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/features/exceptions.prf \
        ../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/features/yacc.prf \
        ../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/features/lex.prf \
        qt.pro \
        texo.qrc \
        /Users/Mike/Desktop/Work/Qt/5.3/clang_64/lib/QtGui.framework/QtGui.prl \
        /Users/Mike/Desktop/Work/Qt/5.3/clang_64/lib/QtCore.framework/QtCore.prl
    $(QMAKE) -spec macx-clang CONFIG+=debug CONFIG+=x86_64 -o Makefile qt.pro
../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/features/spec_pre.prf:
../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/qdevice.pri:
../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/features/device_config.prf:
../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/common/shell-unix.conf:
../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/common/unix.conf:
../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/common/mac.conf:
../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/common/macx.conf:
../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/common/gcc-base.conf:
../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/common/gcc-base-mac.conf:
../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/common/clang.conf:
../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/common/clang-mac.conf:
../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/qconfig.pri:
../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_bluetooth.pri:
../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_bluetooth_private.pri:
../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_bootstrap_private.pri:
../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_clucene_private.pri:
../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_concurrent.pri:
../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_concurrent_private.pri:
../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_core.pri:
../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_core_private.pri:
../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_dbus.pri:
../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_dbus_private.pri:
../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_declarative.pri:
../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_declarative_private.pri:
../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_designer.pri:
../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_designer_private.pri:
../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_designercomponents_private.pri:
../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_enginio.pri:
../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_enginio_private.pri:
../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_gui.pri:
../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_gui_private.pri:
../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_help.pri:
../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_help_private.pri:
../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_macextras.pri:
../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_macextras_private.pri:
../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_multimedia.pri:
../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_multimedia_private.pri:
../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_multimediawidgets.pri:
../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_multimediawidgets_private.pri:
../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_network.pri:
../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_network_private.pri:
../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_nfc.pri:
../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_nfc_private.pri:
../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_opengl.pri:
../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_opengl_private.pri:
../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_openglextensions.pri:
../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_openglextensions_private.pri:
../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_platformsupport_private.pri:
../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_positioning.pri:
../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_positioning_private.pri:
../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_printsupport.pri:
../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_printsupport_private.pri:
../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_qml.pri:
../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_qml_private.pri:
../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_qmldevtools_private.pri:
../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_qmltest.pri:
../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_qmltest_private.pri:
../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_qtmultimediaquicktools_private.pri:
../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_quick.pri:
../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_quick_private.pri:
../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_quickparticles_private.pri:
../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_quickwidgets.pri:
../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_quickwidgets_private.pri:
../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_script.pri:
../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_script_private.pri:
../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_scripttools.pri:
../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_scripttools_private.pri:
../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_sensors.pri:
../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_sensors_private.pri:
../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_serialport.pri:
../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_serialport_private.pri:
../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_sql.pri:
../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_sql_private.pri:
../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_svg.pri:
../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_svg_private.pri:
../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_testlib.pri:
../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_testlib_private.pri:
../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_uitools.pri:
../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_uitools_private.pri:
../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_webkit.pri:
../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_webkit_private.pri:
../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_webkitwidgets.pri:
../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_webkitwidgets_private.pri:
../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_websockets.pri:
../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_websockets_private.pri:
../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_widgets.pri:
../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_widgets_private.pri:
../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_xml.pri:
../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_xml_private.pri:
../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_xmlpatterns.pri:
../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_xmlpatterns_private.pri:
../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/features/qt_functions.prf:
../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/features/qt_config.prf:
../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/macx-clang/qmake.conf:
../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/features/spec_post.prf:
../../../../.qmake.stash:
../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/features/exclusive_builds.prf:
../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/features/default_pre.prf:
../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/features/mac/default_pre.prf:
../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/features/resolve_config.prf:
../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/features/default_post.prf:
../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/features/mac/sdk.prf:
../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/features/mac/default_post.prf:
../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/features/mac/objective_c.prf:
../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/features/warn_on.prf:
../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/features/qt.prf:
../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/features/resources.prf:
../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/features/moc.prf:
../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/features/unix/opengl.prf:
../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/features/unix/thread.prf:
../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/features/mac/rez.prf:
../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/features/testcase_targets.prf:
../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/features/exceptions.prf:
../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/features/yacc.prf:
../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/features/lex.prf:
qt.pro:
texo.qrc:
/Users/Mike/Desktop/Work/Qt/5.3/clang_64/lib/QtGui.framework/QtGui.prl:
/Users/Mike/Desktop/Work/Qt/5.3/clang_64/lib/QtCore.framework/QtCore.prl:
qmake: FORCE
    @$(QMAKE) -spec macx-clang CONFIG+=debug CONFIG+=x86_64 -o Makefile qt.pro

qmake_all: FORCE

qt.app/Contents/PkgInfo: 
    @test -d qt.app/Contents || mkdir -p qt.app/Contents
    @$(DEL_FILE) qt.app/Contents/PkgInfo
    @echo "APPL????" >qt.app/Contents/PkgInfo
qt.app/Contents/Resources/empty.lproj: 
    @test -d qt.app/Contents/Resources || mkdir -p qt.app/Contents/Resources
    @touch qt.app/Contents/Resources/empty.lproj

qt.app/Contents/Info.plist: 
    @test -d qt.app/Contents || mkdir -p qt.app/Contents
    @$(DEL_FILE) qt.app/Contents/Info.plist
    @sed -e "s,@SHORT_VERSION@,1.0,g" -e "s,@TYPEINFO@,????,g" -e "s,@ICON@,,g" -e "s,@BUNDLEIDENTIFIER@,sdf.qt,g" -e "s,@EXECUTABLE@,qt,g" -e "s,@TYPEINFO@,????,g" ../../../Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/macx-clang/Info.plist.app >qt.app/Contents/Info.plist
dist: 
    @test -d .tmp/qt1.0.0 || mkdir -p .tmp/qt1.0.0
    $(COPY_FILE) --parents $(DIST) .tmp/qt1.0.0/ && $(COPY_FILE) --parents texo.qrc texo.qrc .tmp/qt1.0.0/ && $(COPY_FILE) --parents TexoView.h TexoDemo.h stdafx.h TexoViewImg.h .tmp/qt1.0.0/ && $(COPY_FILE) --parents TexoView.cpp TexoDemo.cpp StdAfx.cpp main.cpp TexoViewImg.cpp .tmp/qt1.0.0/ && (cd `dirname .tmp/qt1.0.0` && $(TAR) qt1.0.0.tar qt1.0.0 && $(COMPRESS) qt1.0.0.tar) && $(MOVE) `dirname .tmp/qt1.0.0`/qt1.0.0.tar.gz . && $(DEL_FILE) -r .tmp/qt1.0.0


clean:compiler_clean 
    -$(DEL_FILE) $(OBJECTS)
    -$(DEL_FILE) *~ core *.core


distclean: clean 
    -$(DEL_FILE) -r qt.app
    -$(DEL_FILE) Makefile


####### Sub-libraries

mocclean: compiler_moc_header_clean compiler_moc_source_clean

mocables: compiler_moc_header_make_all compiler_moc_source_make_all

check: first

compiler_objective_c_make_all:
compiler_objective_c_clean:
compiler_rcc_make_all: qrc_texo.cpp qrc_texo.cpp
compiler_rcc_clean:
    -$(DEL_FILE) qrc_texo.cpp qrc_texo.cpp
qrc_texo.cpp: texo.qrc \
        res/stop.png \
        res/u.ico \
        res/run.png \
        res/init.png
    /Users/Mike/Desktop/Work/Qt/5.3/clang_64/bin/rcc -name texo texo.qrc -o qrc_texo.cpp

qrc_texo.cpp: texo.qrc \
        res/stop.png \
        res/u.ico \
        res/run.png \
        res/init.png
    /Users/Mike/Desktop/Work/Qt/5.3/clang_64/bin/rcc -name texo texo.qrc -o qrc_texo.cpp

compiler_moc_header_make_all: moc_TexoDemo.cpp
compiler_moc_header_clean:
    -$(DEL_FILE) moc_TexoDemo.cpp
moc_TexoDemo.cpp: TexoDemo.h
    /Users/Mike/Desktop/Work/Qt/5.3/clang_64/bin/moc $(DEFINES) -D__APPLE__ -D__GNUC__=4 -I/Users/Mike/Desktop/Work/Qt/5.3/clang_64/mkspecs/macx-clang -I/Users/Mike/Desktop/Work/texo/demo/qt -I/Users/Mike/Desktop/Work/texo/inc -I/Users/Mike/Desktop/Work/Qt/5.3/clang_64/lib/QtGui.framework/Headers -I/Users/Mike/Desktop/Work/Qt/5.3/clang_64/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers -F/Users/Mike/Desktop/Work/Qt/5.3/clang_64/lib TexoDemo.h -o moc_TexoDemo.cpp

compiler_moc_source_make_all:
compiler_moc_source_clean:
compiler_rez_source_make_all:
compiler_rez_source_clean:
compiler_yacc_decl_make_all:
compiler_yacc_decl_clean:
compiler_yacc_impl_make_all:
compiler_yacc_impl_clean:
compiler_lex_make_all:
compiler_lex_clean:
compiler_clean: compiler_rcc_clean compiler_moc_header_clean 

####### Compile

TexoView.o: TexoView.cpp stdafx.h \
        ../../inc/texo_def.h \
        ../../inc/texo.h \
        TexoView.h \
        qgraphicsview.h
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCPATH) -o TexoView.o TexoView.cpp

TexoDemo.o: TexoDemo.cpp stdafx.h \
        ../../inc/texo_def.h \
        ../../inc/texo.h \
        TexoDemo.h
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCPATH) -o TexoDemo.o TexoDemo.cpp

StdAfx.o: StdAfx.cpp stdafx.h \
        ../../inc/texo_def.h \
        ../../inc/texo.h
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCPATH) -o StdAfx.o StdAfx.cpp

main.o: main.cpp stdafx.h \
        ../../inc/texo_def.h \
        ../../inc/texo.h \
        TexoDemo.h
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCPATH) -o main.o main.cpp

TexoViewImg.o: TexoViewImg.cpp stdafx.h \
        ../../inc/texo_def.h \
        ../../inc/texo.h \
        TexoViewImg.h \
        qgraphicsview.h
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCPATH) -o TexoViewImg.o TexoViewImg.cpp

qrc_texo.o: qrc_texo.cpp 
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCPATH) -o qrc_texo.o qrc_texo.cpp

moc_TexoDemo.o: moc_TexoDemo.cpp 
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCPATH) -o moc_TexoDemo.o moc_TexoDemo.cpp

####### Install

install:   FORCE

uninstall:   FORCE

FORCE:
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the `.ui` file is referenced in the project file. Add this line to `qt.pro` if it's not there already:

```
FORMS = texo.ui
```

Comment: That line is there already, except it is written as:                     `FORMS += \                                                                                       texo.ui`

Comment: Is that one line? What happens when you execute `qmake && make` in the project directory?

Comment: It is two lines. Did you want me to go to the directory in terminal and type `quake && make` ? If so, I changed the directory to the file that has the qt.pro file in it and ran the command and the result was `-bash: qmake: command not found`.

Comment: Yeah, on a Mac you will have to jump through some hoops to build the project manually. Have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22353555/2970862) for a way to execute `qmake` from the terminal.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I tried what was suggested in the post that you suggested and the error that I got was essentially the same one that I get in Qt creator except this time in terminal. The exact terminal error was `In file included from TexoDemo.cpp:2:
./TexoDemo.h:3:10: fatal error: 'ui_texo.h' file not found
#include "ui_texo.h"
         ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [TexoDemo.o] Error 1`

Comment: Could you add the contents of `qt.pro` and `Makefile` to the question?

Answer (score 0):

You Makefile doesn't contain any ui specific rules, indicating that it was not created from your .pro file, or at least not from this version of your .pro file. (Re-)running qmake might indeed help. You should be able to run qmake from Creator's "Build" menu.